# Update value by clicking Button and checkbox

Tags: oracle, jsp, jsp-tags

One of senior giving me one task that is user information dynamically fetch when manager check on approve(checkbox) and click submit  his task should submit and remove form list manager can check multiple approve(checkbox) i'm written a code(on jsp page not use html) but not understand how to check which checkbox is selected base on employee_id if checkbox is checked true then only data will update and remove from list here is my whole code **im stuck update data base on checkbox selection and button click** anyone's help really appreciate

```
<%@page contentType="text/html" pageEncoding="UTF-8"%>
<%@page import="java.sql.PreparedStatement"%>
<%@page import="java.sql.SQLException"%>
<%@page import="java.sql.DriverManager"%>
<%@page import="java.sql.ResultSet"%>
<%@page import="java.sql.Statement"%>
<%@page import="java.sql.Connection"%>
<%@page import="java.sql.*"%>
<%@page import="java.time.LocalTime"%>
<%@page import="java.time.LocalDate"%>
<%@page import="java.text.*,java.util.Date"%>
<%@page import="java.time.Duration"%>
<%@page import="java.time.Instant"%>
<%@page import="java.util.Scanner"%>



  <%
         String manager_id=request.getParameter("txtemployeeid");
          Connection connection = null;
Statement statement = null;
ResultSet resultSet = null;



        %>

<!DOCTYPE html>
<html>
    <head>
        <meta http-equiv="Content-Type" content="text/html; charset=UTF-8">
        <title>Employee and vendor approve Page</title>
    </head>
    <body>

        <table border="1" align="center">

            <tr>

                <td>FIRST_NAME </td>
                <td>LAST_NAME</td>
                <td>ORGANIZATION_NAME</td>
                <td>EMPLOYEE_ID</td>
                <td>Approve</td>
            </tr>


            <%

                Class.forName("oracle.jdbc.driver.OracleDriver");
          Connection con=DriverManager.getConnection("jdbc:oracle:thin:@172.18.114.213:1821:godb","XE","Spacess");

            statement=con.createStatement();
            String Sql="SELECT FIRST_NAME,LAST_NAME,ORGANISATION_NAME,EMPLOYEE_ID from REGISTRATION_EMPLOYEE where role in ('Employee','Vendor')";
            resultSet=statement.executeQuery(Sql);


while(resultSet.next())
{
    String Employee_id=resultSet.getString("EMPLOYEE_ID");
      %>

      <c:forEach var="item" items="${items}">


      <tr>


              <td><%=resultSet.getString("FIRST_NAME")%></td>
              <td><%=resultSet.getString("LAST_NAME")%></td>
              <td><%=resultSet.getString("ORGANISATION_NAME")%></td>
              <td><%=resultSet.getString("EMPLOYEE_ID")%></td>
              <td>
                <input type="checkbox" name="EMPLOYEE_ID" value="${REGISTRATION_EMPLOYEE.EMPLOYEE_ID}" float:left;>
            </td>

      </tr>
</c:forEach>  

<%
    }


    %>
      <tr>
                            <td style="text-align: center">
                                <input type="submit" name="btnApprovevalues" value="Approve" display:block;> &nbsp;<input type="submit" name="btnRejectvalues" value="Reject" display:block;>
                            </td>
                        </tr>

    <%
        String[] selectedStudentIds = request.getParameterValues("EMPLOYEE_ID");
        String btn_approve=request.getParameter("btnApprovevalues");


    if(btn_approve!=null)
    {

        if(selectedStudentIds.equals(true))
        {

        Class.forName("oracle.jdbc.driver.OracleDriver");
              Connection con3=DriverManager.getConnection("jdbc:oracle:thin:@172.18.114.213:1821:godb","sbigi_gtrg","Spacess");
              Statement st3=con3.createStatement();

              String Update_Timeout="update REGISTRATION_EMPLOYEE set APPROVE='Y' where APPROVE=N";
              PreparedStatement ps3=con3.prepareStatement(Update_Timeout);
        }
    }
    %>


        </table>
    </body>
</html>
```

[image]

Comment: Without mentioning the fact that you've put everything in your JSP, could you at least restrict the code to a [mcve] ? It is unclear what you have and what you are stuck with.

Comment: @AxelH : i updated my question

Comment: I was expecting a [mcve] but you have just added one line of information... so I will do the same. Search for Ajax.